# Append new value to array column

Tags: php, mongodb

How can I insert a new value in MongoDb Column Array?

```
    // Connect Collection
    $collection = $this->mongo_db->db->selectCollection('test');

    // Remove All Document
    $collection->remove();
    // initially Insert abcd Column inside Firstnam Lastname Value
    $test=array('abcd'=>
                    array("firstname" => "Bob", "lastname" => "Jones" )
                    );

    // Insert Value
    $content=$collection->insert($test);

    // get Last Insert ID
    $newDocID = $test['_id'];

    // Append New value in above abcd Array Field Column
    $newdata = array('$set'=>
                    array('abcd'=> array('city'=>"Tiruppur"))
                    );

    $collection->update(array("_id" => new MongoId($newDocID)), $newdata);
```

```
    // Current Result
                {
                    "_id" : ObjectId("55995b0be5ffc4980b000041"),
                    "abcd" : {
                        "city" : "Tiruppur"
                    }
                }

    // But Need Expect Result

                {
                    "_id" : ObjectId("55995b0be5ffc4980b000041"),
                    "abcd" : {
                        "firstname" => "Bob",
                        "lastname" => "Jones" ,
                        "city" : "Tiruppur"
                    }
                }

    // Please be help to Find Solution
```

Answer (score 0):

Use dot notation:

```
$newdata = array('$set' => array('abcd.city' => "Tiruppur"));
```

Comment: Thank You for u r response TECHWISDOM, But This Ans is Wrong,  i am Already try this Code, But Got  Error : The field 'abcd' must be an array but is of type Object in document {_id: ObjectId('559aa69ee5ffc4680c000043')} error code: 16837

Comment: @user1837631, I see. Check out my edited answer and tell me what is going on please.

Comment: @user1837631, You are welcome my friend. I'll be glad if you could mark this as the answer (the V at the left). Thanks.